# "You have 10 votes left for today"... "You have 9 votes left for today"

Tags: feature-request, voting

This is by far, the most annoying behaviour of all annoying behaviours of StackOverflow.

Please let me turn it off. Add a checkbox or something.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3641/ (about the fact that you can't click to dismiss that warning box)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maybe just a warning at 10. The countdown is pretty annoying.

Comment: Great idea! Like it more than a checkbox to disable the warning completely.

Comment: yea, simple to implement too.

Comment: Or a countdown starting from 3.

Comment: Or from 10, then at 5, then at 1.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest that if the warning is removed, a counter should be available somewhere in the profile page so that you can still see how you're doing. Arguably that would be useful to have whether or not the reminder was removed :)

I would suggest that it could appear in the user profile page next to the total votes - so you'd see how much you've voted overall, the up/down votes you've cast *today*, and how many you've got left for today, all in the same area. Obviously the "today" stuff would only be shown to the user themselves.

Comment: I think Jeff is against the idea of showing the countdown as it might psychologically impact the voting behavior. People might vote more cautiously if they are conscious of the cap and this will result in smaller number of votes cast.

Comment: @Mehrdad - but once you reach 10 votes left, there is a countdown anyway.

Comment: @Graeme: True, but you have to cast 20 votes before you reach the countdown. Probably most people will never see it.

Answer (score 4):

We can reduce it to, say, 5 if you like. Would that work?